# CodeIgniter - Array to String conversion error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a function to get a users data based on the user ID. This is the function I have created:

```
    function getUserData($data, $id) {
        $query = $this->db->query('SELECT ' . $data . ' FROM users WHERE id = "' . $id . '"');

        return $query->result();
    }
```

I am calling this method in my home_view.php file:

```
    <?php $username = $this->model_users->getUserData('username', 3); ?>
```

When I do this I get an error saying

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: views/home_view.php

Line Number: 25
```

Could someone please tell me why its doing this?

Comment: probably you're doing something like `echo $username`, and `$username` is an ARRAY of values from your query results.

Answer (score 0):

`getUserData()` will return a database result.  If you want it to return the single value update that function to return the single value.  You still need to make sure the results are valid and handle errors, but something like below should get you started

reference - https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html

```
function getUserData($data, $id) {
    $query = $this->db->query('SELECT ' . $data . ' FROM users WHERE id = "' . $id . '"');

    $result = $query->result_array();
    return $results[$data];
}
```

Comment: That didnt seem to be the fix, Got rid of the error but didnt work

Comment: The question you asked was about the error and why it was happening.  If you are trying to do something else you can pose a new question or edit this one with further details.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting a valid return, when you return using

```
result();
```

codeigniter produces an empty array on failure, otherwise it returns an array of objects. Run the query on the db to see if its doing what you think it is.

I also think you should probably escape those variables you have there....

Answer (score 0):

Your function will return you array of **Standard PHP Object** to access the username you have to add this line after that:

```
<?php

    $username = $this->model_users->getUserData('username', 3);

    echo $username[0]->username;

?>
```

This code only works if you get single record in return.

You can check this by using **print_r()** function like this:

```
<?php print_r($username); ?>
```